# как исправить ошибку toGame() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given?

Tags: python, kivy

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from kivy.config import ConfigParser
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import*
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.scrollview import*
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView


mgolod = 0
cosmodrom = 0
kesh = 15
gorshok = 2
gryadka = 0
ogorod = 0
sad = 0
fermer = 0
ferma = 0
plantaciya = 0
traktor= 0
pribil = 2
golod = 100
day = 1
score = 15
maz = 0
time = ''
string_calc = ""
string_calc2 = ""
size = 0
z = ""
ai = False
zx = "сытость"
fontsize = 30
#backgroundbuttoncolor
bgbc = 'lightblue'

class Menu(Screen):
    def __init__(self, name='menu'):
        super(Menu, self).__init__(name=name)
        #фундаменты
        menubox = GridLayout(cols=1)
        logobox = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        buttonanchore = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='center')
        buttonbox = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size_hint=[.8, .9], spacing=10)
        #Кнопки и т.д.
        startgame = Button(
            text="начать игру",
            font_size=fontsize,
            size_hint=[1, .8],
            background_color="lightblue",
            on_press=self.toGame
        )
        sittings = Button(
            text="настройки",
            font_size=fontsize,
            size_hint=[1, .8],
            background_color="lightblue"
        )
        soon = Button(
            text="-",
            font_size=fontsize,
            size_hint=[1, .8],
            background_color="lightblue"
        )
        #распределение
        buttonbox.add_widget(startgame)
        buttonbox.add_widget(sittings)
        buttonbox.add_widget(soon)

        buttonanchore.add_widget(buttonbox)
        menubox.add_widget(logobox)
        menubox.add_widget(buttonanchore)
        self.add_widget(menubox)

    def toGame(self):
        self.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
        self.manager.current = 'game'


class Game(Screen):
    def __init__(self, name='game'):
        super(Game, self).__init__(name=name)
        #фундаменты
        gamebox = GridLayout(cols=1)
        textbox = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        buttonbox = AnchorLayout()
        #Кнопки и т.д.
        nextday = Button(
            text='-',
            font_size=fontsize,
            background_color=bgbc
        )
        gameinfo = Label(
            text=f"День:{str(day)}\n{zx}:{golod}%\nДоход:+{pribil}\nсчёт:{score}\nогурцов:{kesh}",
            font_size=fontsize
        )
        #распределение
        textbox.add_widget(gameinfo)
        buttonbox.add_widget(nextday)

        gamebox.add_widget(textbox)
        gamebox.add_widget(buttonbox)


class game(App):
    def build(self):
        zxc = Button(
            text='огуречный магнат 2',
            size_hint=[1, .1],
            background_color='black'
        )
        bbb = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        sm = ScreenManager(transition=FadeTransition())
        screens = [
            Menu(),
            Game()
        ]
        for i in screens:
            sm.add_widget(i)
        bbb.add_widget(zxc)
        bbb.add_widget(sm)
        return bbb





if __name__ == "__main__":
    game().run()
```

Comment: Подозреваю что так: ```def toGame(self,value):```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.